# Want to print text from a specific word till the end of that para or till the line which is empty

Tags: java, file, oop, netbeans, file-handling

---

'I want to search for a specific word. if that word is found the function should display that line till there is no empty line.'

---

```
public void loadRoom(String RoomType) throws IOException{
        Boolean a=true;
           File file =new File("RoomDetails.txt"); 
           String separator = System.getProperty("line.separator");
           try{
               BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader (new FileReader(file));
            String line = in.readLine();
            do{
                if(line==separator){
                    System.out.println("File is Empty; No room has been created");
                }
                if(line==RoomType){

                    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                        System.out.println(line);
                    }
                    a=false;
                }else
                {
                    line=in.readLine();
                }

                }while(a=true);


           }catch(Exception e){
               System.out.println("Room not found");
           }
    }
```

I have made this function but it somehow isn't printing anything. the code keeps on running non-stop

- [This is what happens when I call the function and run program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MzWE4.png)
- [This is the file I am trying to print. For example I pass "Laser" as
  parameter to the function it should read from the Line containing
  Laser till that empty line before MINES](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8XFT.png)

Comment: What do you mean with "should display that line till there is no empty line"? Please clarify.

Comment: Don't compare Strings with `==`, use `equals` instead. In `while`, you need `a == true` instead of `a = true`, or just `a`. Your loop runs till `a` (really poor variable name, btw) is `false`, but that only ever happens when you find the line you're looking for, but your string comparison is wrong.